# "decreased", "same", "increased" outcomes : ordinal logistic vs multinomial logistic?

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, ordered-logit, multinomial-logit

I am conducting a study where I have ordinal categorical outcome variables representing frequency for two distinct periods. My goal is to consolidate the responses from these periods into a single outcome with three categories: *decreased*, *unchanged*, and *increased*.

Given the ordinal nature of this new three-level outcome (or is it not ordinal perhaps?), would it be appropriate to use ordinal logistic regression instead of multinomial logistic regression? Or alternatively, are there other methods suitable for this type of analysis that do not require overly complex specifications uncommon in econometric literature?

Comment: Do you mean that you are condensing a continuum into those three categories?

Comment: To clarify, I am not condensing a continuum. The initial responses from both periods are ordinal with five distinct categories. My aim is to compare these ordinal responses across the two periods and derive a new outcome categorized as either decreased, unchanged, or increased.